# How do I get the DDL used to create function based index?

Tags: oracle, index, ddl

I am reverse-engineering the schema of an Oracle database. I have a table and I created a function-based index on it.

```
DROP TABLE Fbi_tab;
CREATE TABLE Fbi_tab (
  a INTEGER, 
  b INTEGER, 
  c INTEGER
);

CREATE INDEX Idx ON Fbi_tab (a+b*(c-1), a, b);
```

How can I generate the DDL used to create this index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DBMS_METADATA package.

> The DBMS_METADATA package provides a way for you to retrieve metadata
>   from the database dictionary as XML or creation DDL and to submit the
>   XML to re-create the object.

For details: Oracle Documentation
[DBMS_METADATA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm)

```
SQL> create table fbi_tab(
  2  a number,
  3  b number,
  4  c number
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> create index idx on fbi_tab(a+b*(c-1),a,b);

Index created.


SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX','IDX','HR') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','IDX','HR')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE INDEX "HR"."IDX" ON "HR"."FBI_TAB" ("A"+"B"*("C"-1), "A", "B")
  PCTF


SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `dbms_metadata`, you can collect information about indexes from `all_indexes`, join it with `all_ind_columns` and finally join with `all_ind_expressions` view to get column expression.
It may be more difficult, but allows you build statement in your own format.